# Microsoft cognitive services form recognizer: assigning names to fields when names are not present in a form

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

I am using the form recognizer api on UN general assembly resolutions. The documents are in a very specific format, though not in the traditional form format that the API likes. They don’t have the field names in the document, but there are definitely fields there. Using the REST API (through Python), I can get the values extracted as part of the key  "**Tokens**”.

My questions is: Can I train the model to assign specific keys to those form components?

For example, in this example, https://undocs.org/en/A/RES/70/204, some key-value pairs I’d like as the output would be

- Resolution: A/RES/70/204
- Organ: General Assembly
- Date: 23 February 2016
- Session: Seventieth session
- Agenda: Agenda item 20 (c)
- Title ID: 70/204
- Title: International Strategy for Disaster Reduction
- Committee: [on the report of the Second Committee (A/70/472/Add.3)]

I could always write some parsing code to look at the position given by the bounding boxes and assign the keys based on that, but was wondering if there was a feature in the API that I’m not aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Form Recognizer requires the keys to be explicit on the form and does not yet support assigning keys to values.